# Python: Parse concatenated JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a giant file (few GB in size). It has a concatenated json, i.e. a few JSON's back to back with no delimiters (not even a comma or newline).

Does anyone know of a way I can somehow parse this? json.load(fileobj) and json.loads(line) both fail with "extra data" errors when the second json in the concatenation is arrived upon.

Even better if the solution allows for character streaming because of the giant size, but that's not necessary.

Edit: A concatenated json is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Concatenated_JSON_2

Comment: Would be easier to help if you provide some example data and expected result

Comment: Did you try the answer to any of these [1,355 previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq+stream+json)?

Comment: That takes care of the second part of your question. So the main problem is your json isn't actually well formatted.

Comment: @Maciek I figure a list of dicts would be a valid expected result. Data is in the format {....}{....}{...}, etc

Comment: We can't help without seeing the format.

Comment: @usr2564301 The jsons are well-formatted. They're just concatenated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Concatenated_JSON_2

Comment: The most trivial testcase is `{}{}`. Literally two empty objects, concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file character by character, writing the result to a file.  Also keep track of brace indentation level.

Whenever you read a `}` character that brings the indentation level to zero, you've read an entire json object.  Close the file, load it with `json.load()`, and start a new file.

However, if the file contains quoted or escaped `}` characters, then this solution is too naive and won't work; you'll need a "real" parser.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer suggests keeping track of indentation. That is hard (although not nearly as bad as XML).

An easier solution is to realize that when it fails with "extra data", the `JSONDecodeError` exception contains a `pos` field which says where that extra data starts. That extra data is your second message. Hence, you want to re-parse the substring before `pos`.

Recursive solution to show the idea:

```
def parseConcatenatedJSON(s:str):
    try:
        json.loads(s)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as jde:
        head = s[0:jde.pos]
        json.loads(head)
        tail = s[jde.pos:]
        parseConcatenatedJSON(tail)
```

Comment: Requires Python 3.5 or better. Before that, a `ValueError` was thrown. So it won't work on the tagged 2.7. But that might be a typo since 2.7 was already EOL when the question was asked